# Log4J2 Plugin vs ThreadContext for printing info about multi tenants

Tags: java, maven, osgi, log4j2, multi-tenant

I have a maven OSGi project and multiple tenants log to the same console and files. I want to print the tenantID in the log messages and currently I have written a custom converter to get the tenantID field. After reading the Log4J2 ThreadContext documentation it looks like that ThreadContext suits for this case. Which is the better way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use  Log4J2 ThreadContext OR  Log4j MDC for this purpose. If my understanding is correct your requirement is to append data against loggers.